# send Hbase batch Puts compressed?

Tags: java, hbase

Is there a way to send a batch of hbase puts, compressed.

I'm setting auto flush to false and I'm using a bufferSize of 2MG. Is there a way to compress the puts in order to send more puts in one batch.

Thank,

Answer (score 1):

You can use any compress library (such as [Google's snappy](http://code.google.com/p/snappy/)) to compress/decompress the data by yourself.